# Requests read raw memory issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, urllib

I have the following function that works for 99.99999..%  of domains for fetching and reading the content from the landing page, but for `http://till.wtf` it runs out of memory on decoding.

```
import requests

TIMEOUT = 10
MAX_CONTENT = 10000000
HEADERS = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'}

def load_url(url, timeout, max_size):
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True, timeout=timeout, headers=HEADERS)
    r.raise_for_status()

    content = r.raw.read(max_size+1, decode_content=True)
    if len(content) > max_size:
        raise ValueError('response too large')

    return {'url':url,'content':content,'status_code':r.status_code}

load_url('http://till.wtf', TIMEOUT, MAX_CONTENT)
```

For `http://till.wtf` it looks like if I use `decode_content=True` the max content size isn't triggered as it doesn't include the content size of the decoded object. So I could put `decode_contet=False` but then this gives me other issues. Another option that works for this domain is to include

```
if int(r.headers.get('Content-Length',0)) > MAX_CONTENT:
    raise ValueError('response too large')
```

This works for this given domain but when `Content-Length` isn't returned this doesn't work.

Another option I have is using something like this:

```
content = b''
for chunk in r.iter_content(1024):
    content += chunk
    size += len(chunk)
    if size > MAX_CONTENT:
        raise ValueError('response too large')
```

Is this my only option in this case? Any suggestions?